# How can I fetch the data from PHP backend making a HTTP get request from angular

Tags: php, angular

I have PHP on server side, and angular at frontend. I need to make a HTTP get request from frontend by passing one parameter fetched from a form. Using that parameter there are couple of third party API calls happening in backend which will prepare the response data. This process is taking a while and in the mean time the http get request is getting `Gateway timeout`.

what is the correct way to execute this scenario? Can I make a separate post call first to start the backend process by passing the required parameter and then prepare the response and keep it ready. Then receive the response data using another GET request.

Is this possible then how or do I need to follow other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue in one of my project, our backend system query execution time was around 50 -60s and by that time, it trigger time out issue.

So we tackled this issue by asking backend team to share a reference-id when we hit API first time and when we received this reference-id, from second time on wards we make call the API using this reference as GET API input.

In backend when API have no reference-id in Input they have a temp table where they will create an entry with a unique UUID(which is the reference-id), and a status to progress save it in temp table.
The backend will return the API response with reference id.  After that they trigger function to get data from external sources, once they got data from external sources, they will save in the temp table against that reference id and make the status ready.
When ever api hit came with reference id they will just query this temp table and until status is in ready the API will response the same reference id telling the data is not ready.

By using this approach Backend system also aware that when reference-id in input they need to just check the status of previous execution and if no references-id they can call their external API.

Comment: this seems to have some logic, let me think over it. If we can also implement similar logic.

Comment: Will the temp table which we will create in first API call be available for the second API call? Will not it get dropped automatically when the first request is closed?

Comment: table need to be there always , 
insert data/a row with reference id and status pending on first api call,
when data ready from external source is ready update status to complete along with data from external source

on second API call don't need to do any CRUD operation just fetch from that temp table and return API response based on status